# Azure AD Connect Single-Sign On

Tags: active-directory, azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to set up my domain for Single Sign-On to Azure-Connected services (Primarily, SharePoint Online).
I have already run through the setup for Azure AD Connect and am currently able to synchronize my directory to Azure. I see my users in Azure and can sign in using an account. The next logical step for us is to enable Single Sign-On, so that our users are able to connect easier (our users are actually located on a subdomain, which is transparent to them and does not completely match their email addresses).
Problem is, during the setup of AD Connect, the option to Enable Single Sign-On was not available. It simply was not on the normal User Sign-In prompt during setup. Has anyone else seen this, or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 1):

if you only deploy Azure AD Connect you can configure what is sometimes called Same sign on but not single sign on. if you want single sign on you will have to deploy ADFS as well.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/EMS-Bundle-05-Azure-AD-5b6d8a90

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ADFS? If yes, then this is a by design behavior. ADFS has already provided the ability for SSO.

> Note for AD FS customers this option is not available because AD FS
>   already offers the same level of single sign on.

For detailed information, here is an [official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom).

Comment: No, We are not using AD FS. We are using AD Connect with Password Synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue

PS... no more ADFS needed see here

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/12/07/introducing-azuread-pass-through-authentication-and-seamless-single-sign-on/

Answer (score 0):

ApatheticRiku how did you get it to work? Did you have to uninstall and reinstall to get the option on the left "User Sign-In" this is all I see

https://snag.gy/xgTdF6.jpg

Comment: No. All I had to do was run the most recent installer. It recognizes that the install is an upgrade and gives you different options.